# SQL: Full Outer Join across two hierarchies

Tags: sql, join, outer-join, full-outer-join

Let's say I have a table of parts that were on a shipment and parts that were on a receipt. I want to match up what I shipped compared to what I received, bound together by a common Shipment Number.

**Shipment Table**

```
SHIPMENT NO    PART NO
 1              A
 1              B
 2              A
 2              C
```

**Receipt Table**

```
SHIPMENT NO    PART NO
 1              A
 1              C
 2              B
 3              A
```

**Desired Results**

```
SHIP. SHIP. NO    SHIP. PART NO    RPT. SHIP. NO    RPT. PART NO
 1                 A                1                A
 1                 B                1                NULL
 1                 NULL             1                C
 2                 A                2                NULL
 2                 NULL             2                C
 NULL              NULL             3                A
```

So the idea would be that there is a full outer join showing all distinct shipment numbers and respective part numbers for both shipments and receipts, but joining them together where they match. The complication is still joining on the Shipment No even if the part numbers don't match.

There are basically two join conditions, one of which is completely optional.

I'm certain the solution is very simple but I can't see how to do this without using unions.

Comment: Always try to include one rdbms tag , SqlServer, MySql?

Comment: so, just to confirm, is the ¨Part no¨ join condition optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE Shipment ([SHIPMENT NO] int, [PART NO] varchar(1))    
INSERT INTO Shipment ([SHIPMENT NO], [PART NO])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (1, 'B'),
    (2, 'A'),
    (2, 'C')
;
CREATE TABLE Receipt ([SHIPMENT NO] int, [PART NO] varchar(1));    
INSERT INTO Receipt  ([SHIPMENT NO], [PART NO])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (1, 'C'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'A')
;

SELECT 
     X.ShipmentShipNO AS 'SHIP. SHIP. NO'   
    ,s.[PART NO] AS 'SHIP. PART NO'
    ,X.ReceiptShipNO AS 'RPT. SHIP. NO'
    ,r.[PART NO] AS 'RPT. PART NO'

FROM Shipment s
FULL OUTER JOIN Receipt r ON s.[SHIPMENT NO] = r.[SHIPMENT NO] AND s.[PART NO] = r.[PART NO]
FULL OUTER JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        s.[SHIPMENT NO] AS'ShipmentShipNO'
                        ,r.[SHIPMENT NO] AS'ReceiptShipNO'
                        FROM Shipment s
                        FULL JOIN Receipt r ON s.[SHIPMENT NO] = r.[SHIPMENT NO]
                )X ON r.[SHIPMENT NO] = X.ReceiptShipNO OR s.[SHIPMENT NO] = X.ShipmentShipNO
ORDER BY 3


DROP TABLE Shipment
DROP TABLE Receipt
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think you got it right. Have you check [**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a080/2) That help when you want show a working answer. Have a nice `text to ddl` function to help prepare the data schema. And a plaint text output so you can paste the output as answer instead of a picture

Comment: Great! I knew there was a basic join style that would accomplish this but haven't previously had a reason to use `full join`. ...which is embarrassing, because I even used the phrase `full outer join` in my post...

Comment: @Justin, they(Full Join, Full Outer Join) are both same. So like Left Join/Left outer join and same holds for right/right outer join

Answer (score 1):

Use `FULL JOIN`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a080/2)**

```
SELECT S.*, R.*
FROM Shipment S 
FULL JOIN Receipt R
 ON S.[SHIPMENT NO] = R.[SHIPMENT NO]
AND S.[PART NO] = R.[PART NO]
```